# Parsing string with parsec that needs to end with particular words?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am working on some programming exercises. The one I am working on has following input format:

```
Give xxxxxxxxx as yyyy.
```

xxxxxxxx can be in several formats that repeatedly show up during these exercises.  In particular its either binary (groups of 8 separated by spaces),  hexadecimal (without spaces) or octal (groups of up to 3 numbers).  I have already written parsers for these formats - however they all stumble over the "as". They looked like this

```
binaryParser = BinaryQuestion  <$> (count 8 ( oneOf "01") ) `sepBy1` space
```

I solved using this monstrosity (trimmed unnecessary code)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Text.Parsec.ByteString
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack, unpack, dropWhile, drop, snoc)
import qualified Data.ByteString as B 

data Input = BinaryQuestion [String] 
           | HexQuestion [String]
           | OctalQuestion [String]
  deriving Show
data Question = Question {input :: Input, target :: Target} deriving Show
data Target = Word deriving Show

test1 :: B.ByteString
test1 = "Give 01110100 01110101 01110010 01110100 01101100 01100101 as a word."
test2 :: B.ByteString
test2 = "Give 646f63746f72 as a word."
test3 :: B.ByteString
test3 = "Give 164 151 155 145 as a word."

targetParser :: Parser Target
targetParser = string "word" >> return Word

wrapAs :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
wrapAs kind = manyTill kind (try (string " as"))
inputParser :: Parser Input
inputParser = choice [try binaryParser, try (space >> hexParser), try octParser]
binaryParser :: Parser Input
binaryParser = BinaryQuestion  <$> wrapAs (space >> count 8 ( oneOf "01") )
hexParser :: Parser Input
hexParser = HexQuestion <$> wrapAs (count 2 hexDigit)
octParser :: Parser Input
octParser = OctalQuestion  <$> wrapAs (many1 space >> many1 (oneOf ['0'..'7']))

questionParser :: Parser Question
questionParser = do
  string "Give"
  inp <- inputParser 
  string " a "
  tar <- targetParser
  char '.'
  eof
  return $ Question inp tar
```

I don't like that I need to use the following string "as" inside the parsing of Input, and they generally are less readable.  I mean using regex it would be trivial to have a trailing string.  So I am not satisfied with my solution.

Is there a way I can reuse the 'nice' parsers - or at least use more readable parsers?

**additional notes**

The code I along the lines I wish I could get working would look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Text.Parsec.ByteString
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack, unpack, dropWhile, drop, snoc)
import qualified Data.ByteString as B 

data Input = BinaryQuestion [String] 
           | HexQuestion [String]
           | OctalQuestion [String]
  deriving Show
data Question = Question {input :: Input, target :: Target} deriving Show
data Target = Word deriving Show

test1 :: B.ByteString
test1 = "Give 01110100 01110101 01110010 01110100 01101100 01100101 as a word."
test2 :: B.ByteString
test2 = "Give 646f63746f72 as a word."
test3 :: B.ByteString
test3 = "Give 164 151 155 145 as a word."

targetParser :: Parser Target
targetParser = string "word" >> return Word

inputParser :: Parser Input
inputParser = choice [try binaryParser, try hexParser, try octParser]
binaryParser :: Parser Input
binaryParser = BinaryQuestion  <$> count 8 ( oneOf "01") `sepBy1` space
hexParser :: Parser Input
hexParser = HexQuestion <$> many1 (count 2 hexDigit)
octParser :: Parser Input
octParser = OctalQuestion  <$>  (many1 (oneOf ['0'..'7'])) `sepBy1` space

questionParser :: Parser Question
questionParser = do
  string "Give"
  many1 space
  inp <- inputParser 
  many1 space
  string "as a"
  many1 space
  tar <- targetParser
  char '.'
  eof
  return $ Question inp tar
```

but `parseTest questionParser test3` will return me `parse error at (line 1, column 22):
unexpected "a"`

I suppose the problem is that space is used as separator inside the input but also comes in the `as a` string.  I don't see any function inside parsec that would fit.  In frustration I tried adding `try` in various places - however no success.

Comment: try this code,  test1 has  error too: expecting space or "as a", right?

Comment: exactly, but test2 works (doesn't contain any spaces).

Comment: Finally, I find a simple solution using Parsec, please see the EDIT of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are working with the pattern: `Give {source} as a {target}`.
So you can pipe:

- Parser for `Give a`
- Parser for `{source}`
- Parser for `as a`
- Parser for `{target}`

No need to wrap the parser for `{source}` with the parser for `as a`.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand you - but in this case I get `parse error at (line 1, column 60):
unexpected "a"` - I append the code I used to the question.

Comment: You do not parse the spaces around the "as a". It expect the "as a" but you provide " as a "

Comment: I think it might be the use of sep1 that forces it to accept two or more spaces.

Comment: interesting. So just using `many spaces` should capture one? But I get the same parsing error.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

As said in comment, the clean parser cannot be reused by **Previouse solution** stated at the end of this post.

It led to develop a small parser using Parsec to handle all the possible situations for end parsing of numeric string separated by space i.e.

1. end with a space followed by non-required-digit character, e.g. "..11 as"
2. end with a space, e.g. "..11 "
3. end with `eof`, e.g. "..11"

and such a parser as below:

```
numParser:: (Parser Char->Parser String)->[Char]->Parser [String]
numParser repeatParser digits = 
    let digitParser = repeatParser $ oneOf digits
        endParser = (try $ lookAhead $ (space >> noneOf digits)) <|>
                    (try $ lookAhead $ (space <* eof))           <|> 
                    (eof >> return ' ')
    in do init <- digitParser
          rest <- manyTill (space >> digitParser) endParser
          return (init : rest)
```

And `binaryParser` and `octParser` need to be modified as below:

```
binaryParser = BinaryQuestion <$> numParser (count 8) "01"
octParser    = OctalQuestion  <$> numParser many1 ['0'..'7']
```

And **Nothing** need to change of questionParser stated in question, for reference, I state it again here:

```
questionParser = do
  string "Give"
  many1 space
  inp <- inputParser 
  many1 space       --no need change to many
  string "as a"
  many1 space     
  tar <- targetParser
  char '.'
  eof
  return $ Question inp tar
```

Previous Solution:

The functions `endBy1` and `many` in `Text.Parsec` are helpful in this situation.

To replace `sepBy1` by `endBy1` as

```
binaryParser = BinaryQuestion  <$> count 8 ( oneOf "01") `endBy1` space
```

and

```
octParser = OctalQuestion  <$>  (many1 (oneOf ['0'..'7'])) `endBy1` space
```

Unlike `sepBy1`, `endBy1` will read next some chars to determine whether end the parsing, and therefor, one space after the last digit will be consumed, i.e.

```
Give 164 151 155 145 as a word.
                    ^ this space will be consumed
```

So, instead of checking one or many space before "as a...", it need check **zero** or many space, so why use `many` function instead of `many1`, now the code become:

```
...
inp <- inputParser 
many space            -- change to many
string "as a"
....
```

Comment: It's cleaner than my monstrosity ;)  However the space then seeps into the parser.  What I would like to learn how to reuse a "clean" parser in such situations. Say I have a second program that would send me the input as `"123 123 123"` (no ending space).

Comment: @bdecaf But why don't use Parsec to extract the input string firstly, say "164 151 155 145" in test3, and then use inputParser to parse it ? which can reuse most Parser except questionParser.

Comment: sounds like an idea.  Need some time to wrap my head around how to do this ;)

Comment: @bdecaf But the extract first approach need to parse same string twice. If need to parse a long string read from file, it is inefficient. I still look for a better way using Parsec to solve this type of problem. Maybe, in general, break string into tokens firstly is elegant approach, but too complex to your case.